# Jquery DataTable plugin worn't effect

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used the Jquery DataTable plugin in a static and small Table . but it doesn't work. the code is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("myDataTable").DataTable();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-body">      

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <table id="myDataTable " class="display">
            <tr>
                <th>EmployeeName</th>
                <th>DepartmentName</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Noosh</td>
                    <td>Psian</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nil</td>
                    <td>AD</td>
                    <td>2000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg2</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg3</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg1</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>

                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("myDataTable").DataTable();
 });
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

but the Databale doesn't work it is like a normal table. where is the problem?

Comment: Try this : https://cdn.datatables.net/

Comment: or on in your code this line   $("myDataTable") should be $('#myDataTable') .you didnt put the ID Selector so it didnt find anything

Comment: @BaktiWijaya: it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue are missing # and your id contain space change from `id="myDataTable "` to `id="myDataTable"`

```
$("#myDataTable").DataTable();
```

And also change tr to thead for table header

```
 <thead>
       <th>EmployeeName</th>
       <th>DepartmentName</th>
       <th>Salary</th>
  </thead>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#myDataTable").DataTable();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-body">      

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <table id="myDataTable" class="display">
            <thead>
                <th>EmployeeName</th>
                <th>DepartmentName</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
             </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Noosh</td>
                    <td>Psian</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nil</td>
                    <td>AD</td>
                    <td>2000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg2</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg3</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Neg1</td>
                    <td>Amatis</td>
                    <td>3000</td>

                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you are right i Missed "#" , I add it , but again it doesn't work

Comment: you need remove space in id="myDataTable " and change tr to thead as updated answer